# "#if __ANDROID_30__" and "#if ANDROID30_0_OR_GREATER" missing?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

After having created a new Xamarin.Android project, the `#if` directives mentioned in the title (and other similar conditions) appear to be missing or, at the very least, not recognised.

Here are the relevant parts of the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-android</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>21</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`#if DEBUG` works fine although not explicitly defined above. I just assumed `#if ANDROID30_0_OR_GREATER` would work without having to explicitly define the constant. Albeit, IntelliSense seems to suggest these without any issues.

[image: Unrecognised #if directive. The warning is: "This call site is reachable on: 'Android' 21.0 and later. 'BackPressConfirmationHandlerV30' is only supported on 'Android' 30.0 and later."]

Although the device selected only supports API 21, the `#if ANDROID30_0_OR_GREATER` is what seems to be triggered regardless (and the same applies for `#if __ANDROID_30__`); switching between a device with API 21 and API 30 seems to make no difference.

Am I missing something rather obvious? How can I get this to work?

Comment: I had test this and found that the code will run no matter the API is which one. So maybe you need to use `Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt` to check the device api.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I'm aware that I could just check it at runtime but I wanted to remove the compiler warning properly, that is, using the `#if` directives. Any idea why it isn't being "recognised"?

Comment: It's a strange problem, the example code in the official document is just this, but it doesn't work as the official document says. This may be a bug.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT As long as I'm not missing something obvious then it's not so bad. If it is a bug, will it be looked further into by the Xamarin development team?

Comment: May be you can report it to the Xamarin development team on the git hub.